# get whole email address from @ symbol PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex

The problem with this method is I don't get anything after `.`

```
$string = "this is a test.email@test.com email address";

preg_match('/\b(\w*@\w*)\b/', $string, $matches);
```

The result of `$matches` is

```
Array
(
    [0] => email@test

)
```

Is it possible to alter the regex to ignore them?

Comment: Ignore them how? What's the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a character class (`[...]`). Also you probably want to use a one-or-more quantifier (`+`):

```
preg_match('/\b([\w.]+@[\w.]+)\b/', $string, $matches);
```

You can include any other characters (such as `-` or `+`) you'd like to match as well.

Answer (score 0):

`.` is not a part of `\w`. Alter your RegEx to something like: `\b([\w.-]+@[\w.-]+)\b`.